# Deserialize a javax.json.JsonObject

Tags: java, json, rest, deserialization, json-deserialization

Through a rest service that `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` i get a JSON object like this

```
{
    "key": "myKey",
    "value": {
      "port": 1234,
      "username": "JimmyTest5",
      "password": "password123",
      "host": "http://myurl.com",
    }
}
```

In my java code i need this JSON to be inserted into the class :

```
public class Input {

    @JsonProperty("key")
    private String key;
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private JsonObject value;

    protected Input () {
    }

    public Input (String key, JsonObject value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }


    public JsonObject getValue() {
        return value;
    }}
```

The JsonObject type is mandatory.
Sadly I can't find any method to make it work. The error I get is

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type [map type; class javax.json.JsonObject, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class javax.json.JsonValue]]

Comment: create a custom Pojo instead of doing ***JsonObject value***

Comment: I don't have that option as JsonObject is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defined in this line of error:

```
Can not find a deserializer for non-concrete Map type
```

Faster jackson don't know what concrete class to use for the field value.

Replace it with a `Map` and initialize value in the constructor with a concrete `Map`, `Hashmap` for example.

Comment: That works like a charm but the JsonObject type is mandatory in this situation.

Comment: @user3525227 you can create a custom class that implements JsonObject and use this class a concrete JsonObject.